# disable cache responses of HTTP GET requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am using Nginx, passenger, and Rails. The rails app is caching responses for HTTP GET requests. Is there a way to disable this? If so, where and how do I do this?

The GET request returns the same response every time. When I run rails locally, without nginx or passenger, on development mode, I don't get this issue. It's only in the production environment that it returns the same response every time the call is made. If the server is reset, it returns a different value.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean "caching responses for HTTP GET"? How is it caching? What is the problem that's causing?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's a bad idea to disable caching, but if you want to so.

in rails app in `production.rb` file, set `config.action_controller.perform_caching` to `false`